# SQL Combination of JOINs

Tags: sql, join

following database:

```
Table MatA:
ID  NomCom_ID   ProFo_ID
1   1           1
2   2           2

Table MatB:
ID  NomCom_ID   ProFo_ID
1   1           2
2   2           2

Table NomCom:
ID  Val
1   Steel
2   Copper

Table ProFo:
ID  Val
1   Sheet
2   Pipe
```

with the following query I get Table MatA with linked inputs:

```
SELECT  M.ID,
  NomCom.Val AS NomCom,
  ProFo.Val AS ProFo
FROM MatA M
  LEFT JOIN NomCom      ON M.NomCom_ID = NomCom.ID
  LEFT JOIN ProFo       ON M.ProFo_ID = ProFo.ID
;
```

result:

```
Table MatA:
ID  NomCom      ProFo
1   Steel       Sheet
2   Copper      Pipe
```

with the following query I get only inputs available in Table MatA **AND** MatB:

```
SELECT A.* FROM MatA A
  INNER JOIN MatB B
  ON A.NomCom_ID = B.NomCom_ID
  AND A.ProFo_ID = B.ProFo_ID
;
```

result:

```
Table MatA:
ID  NomCom_ID   ProFo_ID
2   2           2
```

how is the correct syntax to get this result but with linked items from sub-tables like this:

```
Table MatA:
ID  NomCom      ProFo
2   Copper      Pipe
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the details of what those ID's are, then you would just join onto those tables from the ID and get the value field.

```
SELECT A.ID, NomCom.Val, ProFo.Val FROM MatA A
INNER JOIN MatB B
   ON A.NomCom_ID = B.NomCom_ID AND A.ProFo_ID = B.ProFo_ID
LEFT JOIN NomCom AS n ON A.NomCom_ID = n.NomCom.ID
LEFT JOIN ProFo  AS p ON A.ProFo_ID = p.ProFo.ID
```

It will do the inner join to get you the result of:

```
Table MatA:
ID  NomCom_ID   ProFo_ID
2   2           2
```

Then the extra joins will get you the values and return this:

```
Table MatA:
ID  NomCom      ProFo
2   Copper      Pipe
```

Comment: @Udineska If that worked for you can you tag this as the accepted answer. Thanks.